# Populate textbox with info from combobox

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets, web

I need to create a jsp page to edit data from an oracle database.
I thought that the easiest thing I could do was to create a combobox showing important info 
(in this case: id+ name of the material) but I have problems filling the text fields.

My idea is to fill those fields after the text on the combobox changes, but I don't really know how to do it. I know that with the info of the combobox, I have to do a query to obtain the data and then recall the jsp or something, but I don't exactly if I have to call a Servlet or what is the best way to do it.

Sorry if this question is repeated, but I didn't find any posts helpful.

Some code:

```
    <sql:setDataSource dataSource="bd/login"/>
    <sql:transaction>
        <%--Vamos a hacer una consulta a la bd--%>
        <sql:query var="resultado">
            select * from material order by codigo
        </sql:query>
    </sql:transaction>
    <form name="formActualizar" action="../ServletActualizarDatos" method="POST">





        <select name="select" styleId = "tempId" onchange="ActualizarDatos()">
            <option selected="selected"> -- Elija material --</option>
            <c:forEach var="material" items="${resultado.rows}">
                <option value="${material.codigo}">${material.codigo} ${material.nombre}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select><br/><br/>


        Código<br/>
        <input type="text" name="codigo" value="" /></p>
        Nombre<br/>
        <input type="text" name="nombre"  value=""/></p>
        Resistencia<br/>
        <input type="text" name="resistencia"  value="" /></p>    

        <input type="submit" name="bt" value="Actualizar Material" />
     </form>

    <script>
           function ActualizarDatos()
            {
                String texto = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
                Material m = ServletActualizarDatos.ObtainMaterialFromCombo(text);
                this.form['codigo'].value=String.valueOf(m.getCodigo());
                this.form['nombre'].value=m.getNombre();
                this.form['resistencia'].value=String.valueOf(m.getResistencia());
            }
    </script>
```

Thank you for your help.

///CODE UPDATED, DOESN'T SEEMS TO WORK YET, THE EVENT IS NOT CALLED

Answer (score 0):

You need jvascript to handle event when select box change to set the values of input fields from this select box selected value and selected option.

```
<select name="select" styleId = "tempId" onchange="this.form['codigo'].value=this.value;this.form['nombre'].value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;">
```

Comment: Can you revise then why my code doesn't work now? I suposse I am doing something wrong

Comment: Yes, you are doing wrong, but it's another question.